# How to find the address of a place in an android app

Tags: java, android, api, location

In my app I want to show the latitude, longitude and address of a location. I am able to find an API for latitude and longitude, but is there any API to find the address of a place corresponding to the latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Geocoder to return addresses from lat/lon like this.

```
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.US);

            double lat = 41.146064;
            double lon = 80.642861;

            try{
             List<Address> loc = geocoder.getFromLocationName(lat, lon, 5);
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
             Log.e("IOException", e.getMessage()); 
             Toast.makeText(this, "IOException:  " + e.getMessage(),20).show();
                }
                 //DO something with loc
```

You should know that Geocoder will not always return with a result, it may take a few tries thats why it's wrapped with a try catch. This way you can write to Toast or Logcat with the IO exception msg.

Also you will get the best results when you pass it a locale in the Geocoder constructor as I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

See [Geocoder.getFromLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29)